# Как удалить все одинаковые записи в mysql, кроме одной?

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно сделать запрос к базе в которой есть много записей совпадений. Например по параметрам `id_cabinet = '1' and id_staff = '1'` встречается до 10 одинаковых, как оставить только одно и удалить лишние?

Comment: И сразу вопрос: а какую из них оставить? Первую? Последнюю? Среднюю?

Comment: Возможно, дублирующийся вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/193369/Запрос-sql-на-удаление-дубликатов-из-таблицы-по-одному-полю

Comment: id в табличке имеется?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE t1 FROM my_table t1, my_table t2 WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.id_cabinet = t2.id_cabinet AND t1.id_staff = t2.id_staff;
```