# Выбрать первые записи среди дублей SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица, которая содержит в себе следующие столбцы -
id, foreign_id,id_user,date_add

Если с запросом на выбор всех дублей еще все понятно

```
select * 
from table
where foreign_id in 
  (select foreign_id 
  from table 
  group by foreign_id 
  having count(*)>1)
```

то как выбрать только первую (наименьшее значение date_add, а не по наименьшему id) запись каждого дубля?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запрос SQL на удаление дубликатов из таблицы по одному полю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/193369/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-sql-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного перепишите подзапрос

```
select
  * 
from
  (
    select
      foreign_id,
      MIN(date_add) AS date_add
    from
      mytable 
    group by
      foreign_id 
    having
      count(*)>1
  ) sub
  LEFT JOIN mytable tbl ON (
    tbl.foreign_id = sub.foreign_id AND
    tbl.date_add = sub.date_add
)
```

Comment: Ваш вариант оставляет дубли с одинаковым date_add

Comment: @PashaPash Да. Способа отфильтровать я не вижу. Выбирать произвольную запись не вижу смысла. Автор просил с наименьшим `date_add` он это получил

Comment: Есть стандартное решение для выборки первых (средних / медианных / сглаженных по трем соседним значениям/ сумм от начала и до текущей строки) - оконные функции + функции ранжирования. оформил отдельным ответом. т.е. да, топикастеру скорее свего все равно, но вдруг вам пригодится :)

Answer (score 3):

В SQL Server, начиная с 2008, есть функция ранжирования [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql), которая позволяет пронумеровать строки в рамках одного и того же `foreign_id` в порядке значения `date_add`

```
 SELECT foreign_id, 
        date_add, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY foreign_id ORDER BY date_add) rn 
 FROM mytable
```

После чего остается только назначить этому запросу имя и сделать из него выборку первых строк:

```
WITH Numbered AS
(
     SELECT foreign_id, 
            date_add, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY foreign_id ORDER BY date_add) rn 
     FROM mytable
)
SELECT * from Numbered WHERE rn = 1
```

Для эффективной работы подобных запросов обычно используются POC (Partition - Order - Cover) индексы - индексы, построенные по колонкам из PARTITION BY, ORDER BY и включающие в себя выбираемые данные.

Если для двух строк с однинаковой датой и одинаковым foreign_id хочется получить две строки на выходе - достаточно просто заменить `ROW_NUMBER()` на `RANK()`.